# What's the best way for handle a modification request to cross multiple domains in microservices architecture?

Tags: microservices

What's the best way for handle that a modification request to cross multiple domains in microservices?
Our PM proposed a request for us in some month ago, he hopes that the system can create both of account and a landlord in one interaction. In our system, the account management ability is implemented in the service of the supporting domain, and it serves many businesses (e.g. energy management, property management), the landlord management ability is implemented in the service of the property management domain.
Our team proposed the following solutions at the time:

1. Use distributed transaction(e.g. 2PC, 3PC) - advantages: consistency. disadvantages: more dependency, low performance.
2. Property management service tries to call account management service to create an account if the account does not exist on creating a landlord. if create account failed then create landlord failed - advantages: higher performance. disadvantages: maybe an account was created, landlord not. In this case, the user needs to submit again.
3. Skip this request(lol).

Any better suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, such communication should happen over an event bus. The two services can listen to the same modifiction event, and respond by creating an account and a landlord respectively.

Comment: @Salil But it cannot making either both successful  or both failure.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the respective services to guarantee creation upon getting the event. Otherwise, as you mentioned, you can have a distributed transaction.

Comment: @Salil Yes, you are right.  Hope there are other ways to combine the advantages of the above two.